# how can I solve this error at pandas module? pandas.read_csv(csv name) doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, csv

code:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path='./read_csv_sample.csv'

df1=pd.read_csv(file_path)
print(df1)
df2=pd.read_csv(file_path,header=None)
print(df2)
df3=pd.read_csv(file_path,index_col=None)
print(df3)
df4=pd.read_csv(file_path,index_col='c0')
print(df4)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-4a42e39c37ec> in <module>
      2 file_path='./read_csv_sample.csv'
      3 
----> 4 df1=pd.read_csv(file_path)
      5 print(df1)
      6 df2=pd.read_csv(file_path,head=None)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    700         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    701             # Encoding
--> 702             handle = open(
    703                 handle,
    704                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './read_csv_sample.csv'
```

I already downloaded read_csv_sample.csv file
at Wallpapers(desktop)
but it doesn't work
2nd and 4th line. the error formed.

Comment: Is it working with absolute path?

Comment: The duplicate is somewhat speculative; if your command doesn't work when you specify a _correct_ relative path, probably [edit] your question to add more details about where exactly the file exists and how you are running the Python script.

Answer (score -1):

try this path

```
file_path='read_csv_sample.csv'
```